# Grails: Accessing GORM from a background thread

Tags: grails, grails-orm, executor

I have been struggling with this error for a week now, and I am seriously losing my mind over this! I have tried multible implementations and work-arounds and hacks and what not, but I just keep stubling into just another exception.

I am using the Executor plugin to run a method asynchroniously:

```
runAsync{
   run(...)
}
```

The method initially deletes some objects:

```
page.delete(flush:true)
```

And then later possibly recreating those objects:

```
def page = new Page(type : Page.TYPE_TABLE, domain : domainVersion.domain, identifier : tableName)
page.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

But that fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.ramboll.egs.ohs.domain.Domain#1]
```

The relationship between the `Page` and `Domain` is simply implemented by `Page` having a `Domain` attribute. No `hasMany` og `belongsTo` - as I was discouraged from this in an earlier post due to performance issues.

I think I have tried all thinkable combinations of `save`, `merge`, `withTransachtion` and `PersistenceContextInterceptor`...

How is this supposed to work? Examples please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does it fail? Please show some code that isn't just pseudocode.

Comment: Are you sure the first line saved? Check if it returns null, indicating constraint violation. Also consider `save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` which throws an exception if invalid

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that working in a new thread is the issue, it looks like a standard validation problem. It's saying that the `Page` is null, which indicates a validation error since save() returns the instance if it was successful, or `null` if there's a one or more validation errors. There are a few options:

```
def page = new Page(type : Page.TYPE_TABLE,
     domain: dbUpdate.domainVersion.domain, identifier: tableName)
page.save(flush:true)
if (page.hasErrors()) {
   // handle errors
}
else {
   def pageVersion = createPageVersion(page, dbUpdate.domainVersion,
       con, tableName, dbUpdate.author).save(flush:true)
}
```

or use `failOnError` to throw an exception:

```
def page = new Page(type : Page.TYPE_TABLE, identifier: tableName,
     domain: dbUpdate.domainVersion.domain).save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
def pageVersion = createPageVersion(page, dbUpdate.domainVersion,
    con, tableName, dbUpdate.author).save(flush:true)
```

Comment: Your advice made me realize some rookike mistakes and I have now updated the issue with a more suitable description.